# Formatting contents of a datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a wpf datagrid (.NET 4.0) that contains raw data from a database, and some of the fields need to be formatted to display in a meaningful manner, for example 3 fields containing Year / Month / Day could be formatted together to produce a properly formatted date field.

Is there a nice way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate your View/XAML from your ViewModel, and keep your formatting in the ViewModel as this doesnt belong in the View!

then you can bind your date field to your datagrid and not mess up your XAML or code-behind.

If you look for a good framework to help you keep this design I recommend looking at MVVM Light or Caliburn.Micro

Comment: I've accepted this answer, as I have now got all the changes I need to make made in the Model, and these just look like data that is fetched from the raw database.

Answer (score 0):

You scould not bInd directly you data, but you have to create a function on your model and then bind the function on you view

Comment: I have done, this I just don't (or didn't last night) know how to add new fields into my table